Alder Lake N - ACPI/DSDT - GPIO - Change default value
I purchased an obscure NAS only sold to the Chinese domestic market (Zspace Z4Pro) with a view to using another OS on it since it was intel based. I can boot and run another OS (ESXi/Proxmox/etc) fine however there is no power supplied to the drive bays.
After managing to get a restore image from the manufacturer and ripping it apart I found that power is controlled via GPIO at OS level by means of a kernel module - "gpio-z4pro-sata-power.ko" (as are LEDs - but that's another problem for another day).
I've now mapped the GPIOs (and they are thankfully on the Intel side of things, not the SuperIO)
This is an i3-N305 based board (Alder Lake N)
sata0_power_gpio = pin 17 (GPPC_B_17): (MUX UNCLAIMED) INTC1057:00:681 GPIO 0x04000200 0x00000029 0x00000100
sata1_power_gpio = pin 16 (GPPC_B_16): (MUX UNCLAIMED) INTC1057:00:680 GPIO 0x04000200 0x00000028 0x00000100
sata2_power_gpio = pin 8 (GPPC_B_8): (MUX UNCLAIMED) INTC1057:00:672 GPIO 0x04000200 0x00000020 0x00000100
sata3_power_gpio = pin 7 (GPPC_B_7): (MUX UNCLAIMED) INTC1057:00:671 GPIO 0x04000200 0x0000001f 0x00000100

and can power each of them up by pulling low :
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio681/value

Great. However I'd like this to be the default and not rely upon the OS to handle this.
I believe this should be achievable by means of editing DSDT ? I've dumped the DSDT and this is the only section I can find that relates to INTC1057 but it doesn't appear overly obvious to me how I might achieve my goal?
    Scope (_SB)
    {
        Device (GPI0)
        {
            Method (_HID, 0, NotSerialized)  // _HID: Hardware ID
            {
                If ((GPHD == One))
                {
                    Return ("PNP0C02")
                }

                If ((PCHS == 0x03))
                {
                    Return ("INTC1057")
                }
                Else
                {
                    Return ("INTC1055")
                }
            }

            Name (LINK, "\\_SB.GPI0")
            Method (_CRS, 0, NotSerialized)  // _CRS: Current Resource Settings
            {
                Name (RBFL, ResourceTemplate ()
                {
                    Interrupt (ResourceConsumer, Level, ActiveLow, Shared, ,, _Y41)
                    {
                        0x0000000E,
                    }
                    Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                        0x00000000,         // Address Base
                        0x00010000,         // Address Length
                        _Y42)
                    Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                        0x00000000,         // Address Base
                        0x00010000,         // Address Length
                        _Y43)
                    Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                        0x00000000,         // Address Base
                        0x00010000,         // Address Length
                        _Y44)
                    Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                        0x00000000,         // Address Base
                        0x00010000,         // Address Length
                        _Y45)
                })
                CreateDWordField (RBFL, \_SB.GPI0._CRS._Y41._INT, INTL)  // _INT: Interrupts
                INTL = SGIR /* \SGIR */
                CreateDWordField (RBFL, \_SB.GPI0._CRS._Y42._BAS, CML0)  // _BAS: Base Address
                CML0 = (SBRG + 0x006E0000)
                CreateDWordField (RBFL, \_SB.GPI0._CRS._Y43._BAS, CML1)  // _BAS: Base Address
                CML1 = (SBRG + 0x006D0000)
                CreateDWordField (RBFL, \_SB.GPI0._CRS._Y44._BAS, CML4)  // _BAS: Base Address
                CML4 = (SBRG + 0x006A0000)
                CreateDWordField (RBFL, \_SB.GPI0._CRS._Y45._BAS, CML5)  // _BAS: Base Address
                CML5 = (SBRG + 0x00690000)
                Return (RBFL) /* \_SB_.GPI0._CRS.RBFL */
            }

            Method (_STA, 0, NotSerialized)  // _STA: Status
            {
                If ((GPHD == One))
                {
                    Return (0x08)
                }

                Return (0x0F)
            }
        }
    }

Would love some pointers or any suggestions!
I believe it should be possible to "test" any DSDT modifications by means of overriding it with grub - with a view of then updating the BIOS with this later for a more permanent fit.

As a PoC you may use GPIO hog approach (see meta-acpi project sources for the examples: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/blob/d272b0dbe532d8018e95a5c8250d919a262e4ffa/recipes-bsp/acpi-tables/samples/edison/arduino.asli#L450). Since DSDT doesn’t have _DSD provided for this device, you may want to use SSDT overlay approach, by providing a necessary code in initramfs (https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html).

The real fix is to understand what is in the driver for this and then in similar way add these GPIO resources to the respective Device objects (in terms of ASL), if possible.

I am in vacation till mid-August, I would be able to give a better answer then when having access to my work computer.

Above I meant the SATA driver to check it sources for power resources. If you give more details about that, it would be easier to check. Also, what kernel version are you using? Better to be at v6.10 as of today.

The sata driver is just a JMB585 - it's unaware of this odd power arrangement. The kernel module is literally just poking GPIO values in, the testing I did was just on an ubuntu test image designed for Alder Lake (Ubuntu for Intel IoT platforms). Currently using ESXi on the box so not even a linux kernel, I may choose another OS (unraid/trunas/proxmox/etc) but these come with packaged kernels, hence looking for a platform agnostic approach. I've been knee deep in the 3000+ page N305 datasheet, reading about the DW[0-3] registers and if this is perhaps an avenue I should be exploring

Oh I should add, the GPIO is used with an NPN and Mosfet as a high side switch for the power to the drives. Shocking design because guess what happens during a reboot? It dumps the power to the disks!

(and yes, plan B is going hardware approach - just want to understand the art of the possible here)

The hacking ACPI tables relies on the OS support. Even if ACPICA (interpreter) is used (for example OpenBSD has its own interpreter) it doesn’t mean the _DSD is supported. So, you should amend your question to point exactly to the OS it’s about. I can answer only for the Linux kernel based solutions. That said, there is no platform agnostic approach available.

High chance I will be sticking with an OS with a Linux Kernel (not sure there are many BSD based NAS out there!) so I'm still interested in exploring this avenue. In terms of a platform agnostic approach, I assume then this would fall squarely in the realms of UEFI ? I'm also trying to understand what element would be responsible for setting up the registers (DW[0-3]) and thus their default states for the GPIO pads on this platform.

BIOS and other firmwares are responsible for the configuration of the GPIOs. Then UEFI can modify something (usually not the case for regular use cases) and finally it’s OS responsibility with or without ACPI support.

If you want to set them in an OS independent way, the common denominator here is indeed UEFI, but you have to formulate that in another question.

Thank you 0andriy. I would still be keen to find a solution here, but I shall formulate another question specifically targeting that avenue too. I appreciate your responses.
